# How to get a portion of the response by curl?

Tags: curl, libcurl

Fetching a url by curl causes an unlimited response. When I open the url in the browser, an endless file download will start. The url belongs to a camera which informs about events which occurs on the camera like motion detection and so on. But it's not in the form of one-request/one-response. It's in the form of one-request/unlimited-response. For this, I need to cut the output to get just a segment between "--boundary"'s.
In addition to the description I'm giving an example:

```
--boundary
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 480

<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.std-cgi.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
<ipAddress>192.168.14.227</ipAddress>
<portNo>80</portNo>
<protocol>HTTP</protocol>
<macAddress>b8:41:5f:02:81:45</macAddress>
<channelID>1</channelID>
<dateTime>2019-05-18T17:15:02+03:30</dateTime>
<activePostCount>0</activePostCount>
<eventType>videoloss</eventType>
<eventState>inactive</eventState>
<eventDescription>videoloss alarm</eventDescription>
</EventNotificationAlert>
--boundary
Content-Type: application/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Length: 480

<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.std-cgi.com/ver20/XMLSchema">
<ipAddress>192.168.14.227</ipAddress>
<portNo>80</portNo>
<protocol>HTTP</protocol>
<macAddress>b8:41:5f:02:81:45</macAddress>
<channelID>1</channelID>
<dateTime>2019-05-18T17:15:02+03:30</dateTime>
<activePostCount>0</activePostCount>
<eventType>videoloss</eventType>
<eventState>inactive</eventState>
<eventDescription>videoloss alarm</eventDescription>
</EventNotificationAlert>
--boundary
```

After this introduction, my problem is:
how to use curl to get only the first boundary and don't wait until the response ends, because it never ends? I need to cut whenever I see the first "--boundary".
Another solution instead of cutting is to define a callback function to fetch everything the url sends as response and process it and keep the info.
How to do both?

Answer (score 1):

## Using libcurl

Setup a write callback with [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html). That function needs to parse the incoming data for the boundary string and keep state. When it receives a second boundary string, it returns an error and curl will stop the transfer.

Psuedo code:

```
write_callback
{
   store_incoming_data(downloaded);
   num_boundaries = boundary_count(downloaded);
   if (num_boundaries >= 2 ) {
      /* we have enough, end it here */
      return error;
   }
   return success; /* continue */
}
```

## Using the curl tool

Count the received boundary strings and stop reading after the second. My example here uses awk but you can also just use whatever other tool you prefer:

```
curl https://example.com | awk '/^--boundary/ {a++; if(a>1) exit;} {print $0}'
```

Comment: First problem is that curl functions are used inside a program, not at command line. So I've not awk there. The second one is that curl never returns. So, I remain in the perform function.